# Can't Migrate New Bot From BotFramework

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service

Recently setup a new bot in BotFrameWork.
Setup a App Registration and Function bot to work with Teams bot integration.
However after trying to migrate the bot it gives error everytime.
I have even tried recreating a bot with same info.
I have triple checked the app ID ect..

Anyone have a recommendation?
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veG69.png)

Answer (score 0):

The migration process requires an **active Azure account / subscription**. **The email account connected to your Azure account must be an admin/owner of the bot for the migration to succeed.**

From the migration [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-migrate-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0):

> Before migrating a Functions bot created with Node.js, it is required that you use Azure Functions Pack to package the node_modules modules together. Doing so will improve performance during migration and execution of the Functions bot after it is migrated. To package your modules, see [Package a Functions bot with Funcpack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-migrate-bot?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#package-a-functions-bot-with-funcpack).

Also, note that **Functions bot have not supported since Bot Framework SDK v4**. It is recommended you create a Web App Bot instead, which supports the SDK v4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer so that others can also refer to it when they encounter a similar issue to yours?